# Empty form field return prevention

Tags: php

Sorta new to PHP.

So OK.  I made a very large set of fields on two forms for various products.   The forms work.  The scripting is in PHP and the form is HTML.  Sends an email when you fill it out.

However, it sends ALL fields, even the ones left blank, so that the number column for quantity ordered is top to bottom with zeros, ones, twos, threes, etc.  Not really an error per se, but the person reading it now has to wade through and look for the quantity of say, five to ten different items, and ignore the products with the zeros next to them.

Believe me, the current return is not even close to as easy to read as the return I made below, but rather cluttered and you COULD miss a product request quite easily, especially if busy with many orders coming in.

I did not program it to return any zeros for blank fields, but I do not even want it to return the name of the products not ordered at all.  I just want it to return only the fields filled in-nothing else, but I have no idea how to.

> CURRENT OUTPUT

```
Product #1   1
Product #2   0
Product #3   3
Product #4   0
Product #5   0
Product #6   0
Product #7   0
Product #8   0
Product #9   0
Product #10  1
Product #11  0 
Product #12  0
Product #13  2
Product #14  0
Product #15  0
Product #16  0
Product #17  0
Product #18  0
Product #19  0
```

> DESIRED OUTPUT

```
Product #1  1
Product #3  3
Product #10 1
Product #13 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that your email is built by looping through the `$_POST` array. So something like this should help:

```
foreach($_POST AS $key => $val) {
    if(empty($val)) {
        unset($_POST[$key]);
    }
}
```

Now as you build your email, the zero value POST vars are not even there.

**Update:** Now that I've [seen your full code](http://pastebin.com/CmuazPhk) (which apparently is writing to a file, not directly sending an email) you need to change this line (13):

```
while (list ($key, $val) = each ($query_vars)) {
```

And add a simple check right after it, so you end up with:

```
while (list ($key, $val) = each ($query_vars)) {
    if(empty($val)) continue; // If we have an empty value, ignore and move on
```

Give that a try.

Comment: @user2948063 I updated my answer to check for empty values instead of just zeros. Not sure how your POST data is arriving. You may want to `print_r($_POST)` at the top of your script and see what you're getting first, then you can loop through and clear it.

Comment: Yeah, it returned the same results.  Is there a special position to place the added code to? I cannot paste the whole sript here, I guess because it is a reply and so too large.

Comment: Post your code over on pastebin.com, at least from the top of the PHP code through to how it generates the email contents.

Comment: OK I just pasted it.  "Untitled", I guess as guest?  Never been there.

Comment: I thought this was supposed to send an email? I don't see any email code. Also notice on line six how you do `$query_vars = $_POST;`. So you need to stick my loop right after that (after line 7), and change my loop to go through `$query_vars` since that's apparently what your script is working with.

Comment: Apparently GoDaddy which the customer has does that part.  When I have used my own formmail.pl in the past, I could control the email part, fields, etc.  Let me try your new suggestion anyways.  Let you know.

Comment: I updated my answer, there's a better way to do this now that I've seen your full code. See above.

Comment: << thought this was supposed to send an email? I don't see any email code. Also notice on line six how you do $query_vars = $_POST;. So you need to stick my loop right after that (after line 7), and change my loop to go through $query_vars since that's apparently what your script is working with. >>
OK I struck the code http://pastebin.com/EdKSqnQP

It did the same thing, returning all fields in the email to myself.

Comment: You didn't stick it after line 7. You didn't "change my loop to go through $query_vars". That's not going to work at all. Can you look at my updated answer above?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/TCenATxh

I did not fill the bottom form out in the paste and walked away for a sec.  Captcha hel it up, I had too many tabs, so I repasted it and did the form.

Comment: On my php editor, line 7 is $query_vars = $_POST;, so I put it after that.  Not sure what "change my loop to go through $query_vars" means.

Comment: <<You didn't stick it after line 7. You didn't "change my loop to go through $query_vars". That's not going to work at all. Can you look at my updated answer above?>>
Like I said,  "$query_vars" is line 7 on my editor, but as for "change my loop to go through $query_vars".........no idea how to do that at all.

Comment: @user2948063 I updated my answer above with an alternate solution since that I saw your code. I've said twice already to look at my updated answer, it doesn't seem that you've done that.

Comment: I have and I tried it.  But I am not a php expert, rather a newbie.  In my editor, it is on line 7.  <Also notice on line six how you do $query_vars = $_POST;. So you need to stick my loop right after that (after line 7)> That I tried, to no avail. This part 
<<and change my loop to go through $query_vars since that's apparently what your script is working with.>>
I am clueless about, so....... not understanding it, I copied and pasted it up and down in various places, tried it, again to no avail. I do not know what 
<change my loop to go through $query_vars> 
means and how to do it is all.

Comment: You still haven't even seen my updated answer have you? You don't have to do any of the stuff you just mentioned with my updated answer. http://www.screencast.com/t/g2nBgRi0c1

Comment: OK. I just realized how far up it was, way before the other one about wrapping your code. SOrry.  Never realized it was right after the first response, since the thread filled in so quickly.
<<if(empty($val)) continue; // If we have an empty value, ignore and move on.  Let me try that now.........THANKS!

Comment: OK.  It looks like you suggested, but same result.   |
http://pastebin.com/rge0BYUm